# Why does the spin of a particle system influence the MHV amplitude?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, scattering, lorentz-symmetry

I know that the MHV amplitude for a 3-particle system is the following (based on the colour-ordered Feynman rules):

$$\mathcal{M} = \frac{\langle 12\rangle ^3}{\langle 23 \rangle \langle 31 \rangle}$$

But in my lecturer's notes it is also stated that:

*The MHV amplitude of a spin-2 3 particle (gravitons) system is:*

$$\mathcal{M} = \left(\frac{\langle 12\rangle ^3}{\langle 23 \rangle \langle 31 \rangle}\right)^2$$

*Does the spin influence the MHV amplitude of a system? If not, what does?*

**EDIT:**

**I now know that the scattering amplitude's relation with the spin-*s* of the particles is related by:**

$$\mathcal{M}=\left(\frac{\langle 12 \rangle ^3 }{\langle 23 \rangle \langle 31 \rangle}\right)^s$$

**but I still don't understand what causes this to be true.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scattering amplitudes should obey little group scaling, i.e. a transformation on the momentum that leaves it invariant, which for four-momentum is $p_i^\mu = \lambda^\mu_{~~\nu} p_i^\nu$.

In spinor helicity notation, and for massless particles, this transformation acts on the spinors as $\lambda_i \rightarrow e^{i\theta}\lambda_i$. The scattering amplitudes obey $\mathcal{M}\rightarrow e^{i2h_i\theta}\mathcal{M}$ under such a scaling, where $h_i$ is the helicity of particle $i$. For massless particles then, it is really the helicity that dictates the MHV amplitude, which is obviously closely related to the spin (note that the amplitude above is only true for particles $1,2$ having negative helicity).